# whereHas and whereDoesntHave not working as expected in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**My Query:**

```
Payment::whereHas('subscription',function($q)
   {
      $q->where('ends_at','>',today());
   })->orWhereDoesntHave('subscription')->where('user_id',1)->first();
```

**Output:**

```
App\Payment {#4339
     id: 6,
     user_id: 317,
     package_id: 6,
     amount: 12500,
     phone: "01849744603",
     transaction_id: "F1234",
     confirmed: 1,
     created_at: "2020-11-29 14:29:08",
     updated_at: "2020-11-29 16:40:03",
   }
```

My logic is: when I make a payment, a subscription is created for a specific package for a certain duration if an admin approves the payment. I want to get the payment information of a user if he is not subscribed but made payment or his subscription has not expired. I wrote the above code that gives me an output for the first payment information of the database. Not for the user of the given `user_id` in the query. How should I approach? And what is the problem here? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want to get all payments from a user? i think the wording is a little hard to understand and what do you mean by requested user?

Comment: By requested user, I mean the user of the given `user_id` in the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably about precedence in the logical operators in SQL. Your generated SQL would be pseudo something like this.

```
in (select * from subscriptions) OR ! in (select * from subscriptions) and user_id = 1
```

Wrapping your query in a `where()` with a closure would create parenthesis in the SQL around the first part and secure precedence is correct.

```
Payment::where(function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('subscription', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('ends_at','>',today());
    })->orWhereDoesntHave('subscription');
})->where('user_id',1)->first();
```